# how to print a layout with Print Document Adapter in android

Tags: java, android

i  want to preview a layout for printer and want to print that layout. i already searched a lot but didn't  find any way. i dont want to print many pages of document i just want to print one page one layout.
the layout contains text information, one list view and one imageView of QR code.

I have tried the following code:

```
 private void doPrint() {


        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        // Set job name, which will be displayed in the print queue
        String jobName = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

        // Start a print job, passing in a PrintDocumentAdapter implementation
        // to handle the generation of a print document
        printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(getApplicationContext()),
                null);


    }
```

and this is my Adapter class

```
package com.example.haier.arksolsfollow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.print.PageRange;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
    public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
        computePageCount(oldAttributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        super.onFinish();
    }

    private int computePageCount(PrintAttributes printAttributes) {
        int itemsPerPage = 4; // default item count for portrait mode
         // default item count for portrait mode

        PrintAttributes.MediaSize pageSize = printAttributes.getMediaSize();
        if (!pageSize.isPortrait()) {
            // Six items per page in landscape orientation
            itemsPerPage = 6;
        }

        // Determine number of print items
        int printItemCount = 1;

        return (int) Math.ceil(printItemCount / itemsPerPage);
    }
}
```

my app also get crashes in this line

```
printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(getApplicationContext()),
                null);
```

kindly guide me how to use all call back methods in adapter and how to  preview a layout for printer

Answer (score 4):

If i understood correctly you simply want to take a printout of your current layout. Assuming that i can provide you with an alternative solution. What you can do is first generate a bitmap of the layout you want to print and then pass it to the `Printer Helper`. You can even preview the bitmap before printing by setting it to an `ImageView`.

You can convert the layout view directly to a bitmap using below code.

```
View v = THE_LAYOUT_TO_BE_PRINTED;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
v.draw(c);
```

Then you can print the *bitmap* using `Print Helper`

```
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getActivity());
photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
photoPrinter.printBitmap("layout.png", bmp);
```

Below information is as for the **[Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos)**.

> After the printBitmap() method is called, no further action from your
>   application is required. The Android print user interface appears,
>   allowing the user to select a printer and printing options. The user
>   can then print the image or cancel the action. If the user chooses to
>   print the image, a print job is created and a printing notification
>   appears in the system bar.

**Edit:**
Above method can be used to get a print out of an simple image without using the `PrintDocumentAdapter` itself. But if someone still prefers to use a custom PrintDocumentAdapter as in the original question, well constructed following [article](https://github.com/ShinobiControls/bitesize-kitkat/blob/master/PrintShop/PrintShop.md#custom-print-adapter) in Github will give a clear idea.

Comment: thanks i got the direction i've done it for showing imageView and some TextViews but how will i directly print the whole layout as desgined, i used PrinterAdapter class

Comment: @waseem The mentioned method is way easier rather than creating a custom adapter based on print document adapter. Anyhow if you still prefers it, refer the article in updated answer.

Comment: GitHub link is 404.  Can you provide a fresh link?